# Needing to create a list of reference numbers in Excel

Tags: excel

I need to create a list based on a fixed prefix and suffix but with increasing middle values, for example:

- ABC_001_2000
- ABC_002_2000
- ABC_003_2000
- etc...

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to do it

```
="ABC_00"&ROW(A1)&"_2000"
```

Paste the formula into `A1` (or anywhere, really) and drag down

**Update** 
 
As pointed out by Darren, if you require `ABC_010_2000` rather than `ABC_0010_2000` once you get to your 10th row then you will need to use

```
="ABC_" & TEXT(ROW(A1),"000") & "_2000"
```

Comment: Maybe better to use `="ABC_" & TEXT(ROW(A1),"000") & "_2000"` so you get `_010_` rather than always have two leading 0's.

Comment: Good point - although OP didn't specify so difficult to know which they need